# Area of an ellipse using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Calculate area bounded by the curve
$$\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=\frac{x}{h}+\frac{y}{k}$$
[Hint: Use generalized polar coordinates]

So I see it resembles the equation of an ellipse, but I can't get how to compute the area. I substituted  $x = ar \cos(\phi)$ into equation and got $r=\frac ah \cos \phi+ \frac bk \sin \phi$ and I don't know what to do with it. Could you help me please. Also I computed Jacobian matrix for generalized polar coordinates which is $abr$.

Comment: Complete the square and let $x-\frac{a^2}{2h}= ar\cos\theta$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what "generalized polar coordinates" is referring to, but one approach would be to notice that you can rearrange the equation to get

$$\frac{1}{a^2}\left(x - \frac{a^2}{2h}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{b^2}\left(y - \frac{b^2}{2k}\right)^2 = R^2$$

where $R$ is some constant. That gives you an equation of an ellipse centred at $\left(\frac{a^2}{2h}, \frac{b^2}{2k}\right)$ that you can find the area of with standard techniques.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the center of the ellipse. You can do this by taking the implicit derivative of the equations of the ellipse and find the $(x,y)$ values that make the derivative zero.

   $$\pmatrix{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ \left( \frac{x}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{b} \right)^2 = \left( \frac{x}{h} + \frac{y}{h} \right) \right] \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ \left( \frac{x}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{b} \right)^2 = \left( \frac{x}{h} + \frac{y}{h} \right) \right]
    } \rightarrow \pmatrix{ \frac{2 x}{a^2}=\frac{1}{h} \\  \frac{2 y}{b^2}=\frac{1}{k}} $$

   with solution $$\pmatrix{g_x = \frac{a^2}{2 h} \\ g_y = \frac{b^2}{2 k} }$$
2. Set the polar coordinates centered at the ellipse $$ \pmatrix{x = g_x + r \cos \theta \\ y = g_y + r \sin \theta} $$
3. Plug the coordinates into the equation for the ellipse in order to find the outer bounds for the radius $r$ in terms of the angle $\theta$

   $$ \left( \frac{\frac{a^2}{2 h} + r \cos \theta}{a}\right)^2 + \left( \frac{\frac{b^2}{2 k} + r \sin \theta}{b} \right)^2 = \left( \frac{\frac{a^2}{2 h} + r \cos \theta}{h} + \frac{\frac{b^2}{2 k} + r \sin \theta}{h} \right) $$

   and solve for $r \rightarrow R$ to get

   $$ R(\theta) = \frac{a b}{2 h k} \sqrt{ \frac{a^2 k^2 + b^2 h^2}{ a^2 + ( b^2-a^2) \cos^2 \theta} } $$
4. Time for the area integral using the polar area element ${\rm d}A = r\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta$

   $$ A = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{R(\theta)} r\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta $$

   $$ A = \int_0^{2\pi} \tfrac{1}{2} R^2(\theta) \,{\rm d}\theta $$

   $$ A = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ a^2 b^2 (a^2 k^2 + b^2 h^2)}{8 h^2 k^2 (a^2 + ( b^2-a^2) \cos^2 \theta)} \,{\rm d}\theta $$

   $$ A = \pi a b\; \frac{a^2 k^2 + b^2 h^2}{4 h^2 k^2} $$

Answer (score 0):

$x = ar\cos\theta\\
y = br\sin\theta$

The Jacobian $dx\ dy = ab r\ dr\ d\theta$

$r = \frac {a}{h}\cos\theta + \frac {b}{k} \sin\theta$

Limits of integration... we need $r \ge 0$

$\frac {a}{h}\cos\theta + \frac {b}{k} \sin\theta = 0\\
\tan \theta =  -\frac {ak}{hb}$

$-\arctan \frac {ak}{hb}\le \theta \le -\arctan \frac {ak}{hb}+\pi$

let $\phi = -\arctan \frac {ak}{hb}$

$\int_{\phi}^{\phi+\pi} \frac 12 ab r^2 d\theta\\
\frac 12 ab \int_{\phi}^{\phi+\pi} (\frac {a}{h} \cos \theta + \frac {b}{k} \sin\theta)^2 d\theta$

$\frac 12 ab \int_{\phi}^{\phi+\pi} (\frac {a^2}{h^2} \cos^2 \theta + \frac {b^2}{k^2} \sin\theta + 2\frac {ab}{hk} \sin\theta\cos\theta)\ d\theta\\
\frac 14 ab \int_{\phi}^{\phi+\pi} \left(\frac {a^2}{h^2} (1+\cos 2\theta) + \frac {b^2}{k^2} (1-\cos2\theta) + \frac {ab}{hk} \sin 2\theta\right)\ d\theta$

And now for a little magic when we integrate sine and cosine functions of $2\theta$ over an interval of length $\pi$, they will evaluate to $0.$

$\frac 14 ab\pi (\frac {a^2}{h^2} + \frac {b^2}{k^2})$